# Configuring MongoDB with multiple replicas on kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to configure a MongoDB on my kubernetes cluster with multiple replica instances (3 in my case). For this I'm using a MongoDB [community operator](https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator). Additionally I'm creating a load balancer to ensure that load will be distributed between these 3 instances:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
  labels:
    name: mongo
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    app: mongodb-svc
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Problem occurs when I try to connect to it to write anything. Command:

```
./mongo mongodb://admin:{password}@{load_balancer_ip}:27017/admin?authSource=admi
```

I'm getting an error: `not master` when connection is created to secondary instance. Based on what I have found this seems to be expected. But if I have any application that wants to read and write to mongodb, how can I ensure that for write primary is always selected, but for reads everything else?

Comment: Which version of Kubernetes did you use and how did you set up the cluster? Did you use bare metal installation or some cloud providor?

Comment: I'm using GKE, but I don't think that it makes any difference. Version is 1.19.

Comment: It is very important to reproduce your problem. What do you mean by: "I'm creating a load balancer"? How did you test your connection?

Comment: I have created a LoadBalancer with config that I have written above. LoadBalancer in GKE is going to randomly select one of three instances (all of them have the same label name:mongo). Command that I'm using to connect to the database I have added to the post.

Comment: Did you see [this page](https://docs.mongodb.com/kubernetes-operator/v1.12/reference/troubleshooting/) about troubleshooting?

Comment: Mikolaj, it's a different operator (I'm using a community operator). Also please note that I don't have a problem with installing operator and deploying mongodb. Question is more theoretical, how can I configure my application in the future to use all three instances of mongodb?

Comment: Did you use installation MongoDB ReplicaSet dedicated to external access, i.e. a feature called `replicaSetHorizons`? Look at this [github page](https://github.com/mongodb/mongodb-kubernetes-operator/issues/483#issuecomment-878319275). Is your cluster private or not?